# ¿Cómo usar la placa principal de la hoverboard, reemplazando los giroscopios y el sensor de corte, con arduino?

Tags: arduino

He visto proyectos que utilizan la placa de la hoverboard para controlar sus motores, lo hacen flasheando la placa principal; falsificando los datos de la placa del giroscopio,donde están los sensores de corte de luz; también con raspberry pi, usando los pines SCL y SDA; por último con un convertidor USB FTDI de 3.3V y un programa de arduino para simular los datos del giroscopio. Intento replicar esto que describo usando solamente un arduino nano para enviar la data... Pero no me funciona, si alguien lo ha hecho solo con el puerto serial o la librería Software Serial de arduino por favor comente, gracias. 
Estoy usando este codigo:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial9.h>

#define MOSI 11
#define MISO 12
#define TX MOSI
#define RX MISO
#define LEDPIN 13

SoftwareSerial9 mySerial(RX,TX);

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(26315);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

char c = ' ';
signed int sp=0;

void loop() {
  Serial.println(c);
  if(c == ' ') {
    sp=0;
  } else if(c == 'q') {
    sp -= 10;
  } else if(c == 'w') {
    sp += 10;
  } else if(c == '2') {
    sp += 100;
  }  else if(c == '1') {
    sp -= 100;
  }
  Serial.print("speed ");
  Serial.println(sp);
  Serial.print(" low byte ");
  Serial.print((sp & 0xFF), HEX);
  Serial.print(" high byte ");
  Serial.println((sp >> 8) & 0xFF, HEX);
  do {
      mySerial.write9(256);
      mySerial.write9(sp & 0xFF);
      mySerial.write9((sp >> 8) & 0xFF);
      mySerial.write9(sp & 0xFF);
      mySerial.write9((sp >> 8) & 0xFF);
      mySerial.write9(85);
      delayMicroseconds(300);
  } while(!Serial.available());
  c=Serial.read();
}
```

He visto estos links:
http://drewspewsmuse.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-i-hacked-self-balancing-scooter.html

https://hackaday.io/project/158256-hoverbot

https://github.com/isabellesimova/Hoverbot
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Aaron... Par evitar reportes o puntuaciones negativas te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [ask] y edites o elimines tu pregunta en base a esas recomendaciones... Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones lo que seguramente te va llevar a cerrarla

Comment: Dices que no te funciona, se más especifico por favor, un error puede estar en cualquier parte del código, si no sabemos cual es el error no podremos darle una pronta solución... Mientras mas detalles nos des, más fácil será ayudarte... Mientras tanto te reitero, ve a [ask] para más información

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de romperme la cabeza varios días probando códigos distintos, esto me funcionó:
Primero: calcular la velocidad correcta de los baudios enviados del giroscopio a la placa que controla las ruedas o motores brushles que usa el hoverboard (en mi caso "31536") y simularlos con la función ""Serial.write([datos_en_hexadecimal],[cantidad_de_bits]);"" pude escribir los mismos datos que mandaba la tarjeta del giroscopio, los datos eran de la rueda en movimiento y la rueda detenida. Con el software de Saleae (un analizador de datos) pude ver dichos datos. No sé si para otros patines serán los mismos comandos, pero me funcionó. Aquí el código en arduino(aunque muy rudimentario):

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(31536,191);
delayMicroseconds(126);
  Serial.write(0x1FF);
  Serial.write(0x1C8);
  Serial.write(0x153);
  Serial.write(0xEF);
  Serial.write(0x179);
  Serial.write(0x1E5);
  Serial.write(0x01E);
  Serial.write(0x0FE);
  Serial.write(0x01E);
  Serial.write(0x0FE);
  Serial.end();
  pinMode(5,INPUT); //switch avanza
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  pinMode(6,INPUT); //swtich detener 
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
}

void loop() {

  if(digitalRead(6)==LOW)
  {
   AA();
 delayMicroseconds(126);
  NUMEROS();
 delayMicroseconds(126);
  UNO();
 delayMicroseconds(126);
  DOS();
 delayMicroseconds(126);
   UNO();
 delayMicroseconds(126);
  DOS();
 delayMicroseconds(126);
   }



  if(digitalRead(5)==LOW)
  {
    TRES();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
    CUATRO();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
    CINCO();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
    CUATRO();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
    CINCO();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
    SEIS();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
    SIETE();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
    SIETE();
    delayMicroseconds(126);
  }

}
//detener
 void AA()
 {
   Serial.begin(31536,1191);

   Serial.write(0x0AA); 
   Serial.end();
 }

  void NUMEROS()
 {
   Serial.begin(31536,191);

   Serial.write(0x057);
  delayMicroseconds(126);
  Serial.write(0x057);
  delayMicroseconds(126);
   Serial.write(0x100);
   Serial.end();
 }
 void UNO()
 {
  Serial.begin(31536,1191);

  Serial.write(0x01E); 
  Serial.end();

 }
 void DOS()
 {
 Serial.begin(31536,191);

Serial.write(0x0FE); 
  Serial.end();
 }
 ///////////////////////////////////
 //AVANZA
 //7777777777777777777777777777777777
 void TRES()
 {
  Serial.begin(31536,191);

Serial.write(0x100); 
  Serial.end();
 }
 void CUATRO()
 {
  Serial.begin(31536,1191);

Serial.write(0x0ED); 
  Serial.end();
 }
 void CINCO()
 {
  Serial.begin(31536,191);

Serial.write(0x0FD); 
  Serial.end();
 }
 void SEIS()
 {
  Serial.begin(31536,1191);

Serial.write(0x055); 
  Serial.end();
 }
 void SIETE()
 {
  Serial.begin(31536,1191);

Serial.write(0x04E); 
  Serial.end();
 }
```